Is it safe to reinstall Windows 10 on an infected pc using a not infected boot USB flash drive?
I have two PCs:

PC A infected
PC B not infected

I created a Windows 10 boot USB flash drive on PC B with the tool offered by Microsoft.
Assuming that the boot USB flash drive is not infected and that the viruses, malwares etc… on PC A are only on the hard disk (not on the bios, firmware etc…), it is safe to format the infected disk via the boot USB flash drive (with subsequent reinstallation of windows)?
That is: Is there no way that viruses/malwares etc… from PC A's disk infect the USB flash drive during PC A booting (and formatting and reinstalling Windows) via the USB flash drive itself?

Yes, it's safe. Make sure to remove all partitions during the installation process.

As you state, you assume that formatting the drive is enough to remove all malware, which is not necessarily the case. Yes, it is possible to infect the USB. However, if PC A is completely off (ideally, unplugged and laptop battery disconnected to assure not in a sleep state before booting), though, there is a good chance you could safely format the drive (removing all partitions) and reinstall Windows. After installation, do a thorough offline scan using different tools from the installed AV before booting,
